# How to insert html form element between label tag and text of label tag in jade

Tags: node.js, pug

I need to generate following html markup in jade

```
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
```

My try:-

```
.checkbox
  label Remember me
    input(type="checkbox")
```

generates

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      "Remember me
            "
       <input type="checkbox"> 
    </label>
</div>
```

How can we place element "checkbox" infront of "Remember me" label text?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried nesting it like this?

```
.checkbox
  label
    input(type="checkbox")
    | Remember me
```

Comment: Had same problem this fixed it! Cheers. Still couldn't figure out (without trying too hard) to have the checkbox *after* the label, but this will do.